# No such element exception Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to login to a webpage using Selenium but when I enter the relevant email address and try to click continue I get the no such element exception.

```
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get('https://manage.statuspage.io/login')
email = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
email.clear()
email.send_keys('XXX')
driver.find_element_by_id("login-btn").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("login-submit").click()
```

The error occurs on the last line. [image]

As you can see I'm searching for this continue button via id 'login-submit' but it says that it doesn't exist.
Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After clicking

```
driver.find_element_by_id("login-btn").click()
```

It takes you to another page where the `login-submit` element is presented.
But you trying to click this element immediately after clicking on element on previous page while the new page is still not loaded.
You should add a wait to wait for that element on the second page to appear before accessing it.
This should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Safari()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get('https://manage.statuspage.io/login')

email = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "email")))
email.clear()
email.send_keys('XXX')
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-btn"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-submit"))).click()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explicitWait` like below to click on the desired button

```
driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("email")

OR

email = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "email")))
email.send_keys('email')

btnLogin = WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID,"login-btn")))
btnLogin.click()
```

**import**

```
from selenium import  webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the element/locator to appear on the webpage.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver.find_element_by_id("login-btn").click()
login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.ID, 'login-submit')))
login_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

What happened sometime when you send request from a script it returns you page with different ids or class names. After `driver.get('https://manage.statuspage.io/login')` line save the webpage as .html file and see the id or class name there.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I forgot to mention that once I enter email and click continue on the link above, it takes me to another page where I have to click continue again.